# Asian Characters Not Showing on <optgroup> label

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple test123.aspx page in Visual Studio 2010 (C#), with this code on it:

```
<select id="categoryFilter" name="categoryFilter">
<optgroup label="业务议题">
<option value="保险定价和驾驶者行为">保险定价和驾驶者行为</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="业务议题">
<option value="人力资源">人力资源</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="业务议题">
<option value="再保险服务">再保险服务</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

The problem is that when I bring up the page in any browser (chrome or firefox or IE), the 2nd and 3rd < optgroup > labels do NOT appear in the selector, while the first < optgroup > does appear.  All three < option > values appear.  When I view source on the page, I see the exact code above.

Not sure how relevant it is, but I do have these two tags in the  at the top:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Anyone know how I can make the 2nd and 3rd  labels appear in the browser?

[image: missing optgroup]

Comment: Add a little picture. People might spot from the looks what's wrong

Comment: Resave your file to make sure it's in UTF-8. It appears you have some invalidly encoded characters in your optgroup labels.